# How does asychronous programming work in Netty? Does it make things more chatty?

Tags: java, asynchronous, netty

Normally you make a call to a service, it blocks until a thread in the pool is available and then it returns a result.

With Netty, or futures in general, you get don't block and return immediately.  Only when you actually need the value you call .get() or whatever the API is and then you will block till you receive data back.

When dealing with services, or client/server model, this means you will connect/disconnect from the server more so when doing asych. programming correct?  (with the benefit of not blocking).

Is this correct?

Is Netty basically designed using SEDE (staged event-driven architecture) and using Java's NIO data types).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.

Using Netty asynchronously means that operations that manage connections and push I/O around are executed in separate threads and the original caller is later informed of the outcome of the requested operations, or an interested listener is called back when there is data available to be read.

Your application threads can block if you want them to, but this is not necessary since you can define a callback that will be executed when the asynchronous operation completes.

> *When dealing with services, or client/server model, this means you will connect/disconnect from the server more so when doing asych
>   programming correct? (with the benefit of not blocking). Is this
>   correct?*

Virtually nothing in that paragraph is correct.

I recommend [this tutorial](http://seeallhearall.blogspot.com/2012/05/netty-tutorial-part-1-introduction-to.html) as a better explanation of these fundamental concepts.(full disclosure, I wrote it).

Comment: excellent, that is a great writeup thanks I'll look that over.  BTW, do you think this model will always be more scalable than using threadpools?  how can one prove that?

Comment: Well, it *does* use thread pools, but if you mean, will it be more scalable than using traditional blocking I/O invoked in separate [thread-pool] threads, I'm afraid I have to give you the stock answer: It depends. The hard features of non-blocking NIO (like Netty) are the elimination of Thread-Per-Connection and elimination of polling type functions that suck up bandwidth and CPU. The soft features are more diffused, but I think the Netty pipeline and encoder/decoder architecture lends itself to very efficient network I/O processing, but it is not exclusive to NIO. Know what I mean ?

Comment: Sort of :) Looking forward to part 2 to put the theory into a real world scenerio like ajax and long polling on the web. thanks man!

Comment: Hi @Nicholas: One quick question. So if netty delegates the process of I/O to other threads which when completed are used(talking about result) using callback functions, then is it necessary that they also perform the function of I/O in a non blocking way or is it the blocking way? I guess it is blocking way. But I heard netty is non blocking i/o. How does non blocking I/O happen here?